# Voting in a poll with Telegram Bot

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot

Is there any way to vote in a telegram poll with a bot? I tried to use [telepot](https://pypi.org/project/telepot/) and [python-telegram-bot](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot). I can get poll id, chat_id, options and all the relevant data,  but can not find any way to implement [messages.sendVote()](https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.sendVote) method described in telegram api docs.

Answer (score 0):

`messages.sendVote` is a method from the Telegram API, not the Bot API. All available methods of the Bot API can be found [here](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api), which does not include voting in polls.